# MS-Windows scheduler control (or otherwise) -- test application performance on slower CPU?

Tags: windows, emulation, scheduler, cpu-speed, slowdown

Is there some tool which allows one to control the MS-Windows (XP-SP3 32-bit in my case) scheduler, s.t. a target application (which I'd like to test), operates as if it is running on a slower CPU. Say my physical host is a 2.4GHzv Dual-Core, but I'd like the application to run as if, it is running on a 800MHz/1.0GHz CPU.

I am aware of some such programs which allowed old DOS games to run slower, but AFAIK, they take the approach of consuming CPU cycles to starve the application. I do not want such a thing, and also would like to have higher precision control on the clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you'll find software that directly emulates the different CPUs. But something like [ProcessLasso](http://www.bitsum.com/prolasso.php) would let you control a programs CPU usage. Thus simulating, in a way, a slower clock speed.

I also found this blog entry with many other ways to throttle your CPU: [Windows CPU throttling techniques](http://grandstreamdreams.blogspot.com/2008/07/windows-cpu-throttling-techniques.html)

Additionally, if you have access to VMWare you could setup a resource pool with a limited CPU reservation.

Comment: Thanks @Sorax. Voted it up. Will try some of the options listed (after understanding the theory of how they do what they claim to do).